# Unable to execute two queries in mySqli using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am new in php and mySql. I am trying to execute two queries in mysql using php. The first one verify the username and password. The second one then update time to that username and password in database. The username and password is getting from Android activity using JSON. The android page is connected with this php page and mysql database. But the problem is I am not getting output of both the queries. If the flag is '1' then in android activity, this will display a toast that login success and if flag is '0' then Login failed.But I am neither getting success nor failed. Also If I hardcode the query, then it is working properly. Here is my code :

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pwd='--';
$db='db_name';

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed");
mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die("database selection failed");



$name = @mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Uname']); # Secure the input!
$password =@mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
//$time = @strtotime(exec("date"));
$time1 = new DateTime();
$time=$time1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $time;


$flag['code']=0;
$select1="select * from Insert1 where Uname='$name' AND Password='$password'";
$select2="update Insert1 SET Time=NOW() where Uname='$name' AND Password='$password'";

$r=mysqli_query($con,$select1); 
$s=mysqli_query($con,$select2);

if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) 
{ 
   $flag['code']=1;
}
print(json_encode($flag));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Clue: Pass DB connection parameter to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development.

Comment: I did...but the flag is not setting to '1' even the Username and Password is correct...nd time is not updating too... :(

Comment: `Undefined index:Uname in /var/www/insert3.php on line 16 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string`
same for password and also `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource`...:(

Comment: First start by getting rid of the `@` symbol in `name = @mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Uname']);` then do `name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Uname']);` and do the same for the other one. You suppress errors doing that.

Comment: If you still get that same error message `Undefined index:Uname` after doing that, then it will be because your form element is either not named, or is not spelled the same. I.e.: `name="Uname"`

Comment: I didn't get your solution..
YOU MEAN :
`$name = @mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Uname']);`
only this one or :
`$name = @mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Uname']);`
`name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Uname']);` BOTH..??

Comment: No, use only one of them. `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Uname']);` with the added `i`

Comment: Why do use @ symbol when you developing an application? It is hiding errors.

Comment: well..its working now but I am not getting flag... :(

Comment: 'Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter'

Comment: Try adding `if($s){echo "success";}`

Comment: both the queries are working fine but I want to set flag to either 0 or 1 and send it to android using json...:(

Comment: Don't escape your values, use bind vars instead.... if you're learning MySQLi then prepared statements with bind vars are a lot cleaner and safer

Comment: My code is working fine now..but I am not getting flag value from php to android...I am stuck here now... Look at the last line..` $flag['code']=1;` if this will be 1 then the toast will display in android...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the `JSON` flag in your android app because, you are echo'ing the time earlier in your code. This is considered as invalid `JSON`.

So comment it out `//echo $time;`, and it should work fine.

Comment: thnaxxx...thank you very muchh... :) :)
Its working fine now... :)